# MySQL SELECT rows with string but not other strings doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql

I have text data in a column in a table in MySQL. I am trying to select only those rows that have:

```
SELECT * FROM `leganalyse_unitsub` WHERE `content` LIKE '%Act%' AND `content` NOT LIKE '%this Act%' AND `content` NOT LIKE '%Act (%' AND `content` NOT LIKE '%[Act%'
```

I am trying to get *only* those rows that have the string "Act" in it, but these rows should also not have the strings:
"this Act", "Act (", "[Act".

However, after executing query, I get rows like:
"(11)  Where the Registrar discloses and makes available for public inspection the particulars of a public accountant’s residential address, the Registrar must give notice of that fact to the public accountant."
Which do not even have the word "Act" at all.

Why, and how do I modify the query to get what I want?

Comment: The record contains 'fact' that is matched to your '%Act%' :) You can try to use `content RLIKE '[[:<:]]Act[[:>:]]'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a nested SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `leganalyse_unitsub` WHERE `content` LIKE '%Act')
 WHERE `content` NOT LIKE '%this Act%' AND `content` NOT LIKE '%Act (%' AND `content` NOT LIKE '%[Act%'
```